# XML timestamp through PHP

Tags: php, xml, timestamp

Hi I want to automatically generate a current timestamp in XML format when I run my PHP script. How do I do this?

Heres the XML section of my code:

```
$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('Alive');

if($res === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $xml->startElement("Event");

  $xml->writeAttribute('sessionid', $row['sessionid']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('eventid', $row['eventid']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('BetStatus', $row['BetStatus']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('EventStatus', $row['EventStatus']);
  $xml->writeAttribute('activestatusid', $row['activestatusid']);

  $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();

header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml->flush();
```

Comment: The way to output an ISO 8601 formatted timestamp is [`date('c')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Where you place this result in your XML is up to you.

Comment: Hi, sorry can you be a bit clearer on the actual code I need to put in? Thanks.

Comment: Something like `$xml->writeAttribute('timestamp', date('c'));`. This will add an attribute named `timestamp` to each `<Event>` node.